# How to configure a different virtual directory for web site project with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have a c# Web Site type project which was developed in VS 2012. I want to use VS 2015 and I have trouble specifying a different virtual directory than the default root which is /.

In vs 2012, in the sln file there are these lines:

```
VWDPort = "59903"
VWDDynamicPort = "true"
VWDVirtualPath = "/myapp"
```

and everything works as expected, i.e. when the app launches in the browser it goes to: http://localhost:59903/myapp.

I opened the solution in VS 2015 and vs creates a hidden .vs folder where it puts the applicantionhost.config file under the .vs\config folder.

This is the entry it creates for the Web Site project:

```
<site name="My Web Application" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\costa\Documents\webapps\My Web Application" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59903:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

I tried to play with the path settings of the application and virtualDirectory elements but nothing works.

If I set the path for the application element, the web site project doesn't load. If I leave it as is and set the path of virtualDirectory to let's say /myapp I get HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error, Module: AspNetAppInitializationFailureModule, Handler: PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0 or ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 depending on the url that I try to access.

If I set the paths to just "/" everything works fine.

What puzzles me is that, when I select the Web Site project in the solution explorer, in the properties window the SSL URL and URL properties are disabled. I don't know where it's getting them from. I thought the URL comes perhaps come from the applicationhost.config file.

In the web site property pages window, under Start Options, I have Start Action = Use current page, Server = Use default Web Server.

I am using VS2015 with Update 3 on a windows 2008 R2 SP1 VM (don't ask me why it's like this).

Any ideas?

I did do some research but I couldn't find anything. One other obscure thing (imo) is the ability to create sites or virtual directories in IIS express by choosing: New Web Site -> Browse -> select Local IIS on the left side. I am not too sure what this has to do with an existing web site project.

Thanks

Comment: Did you right click on Project -->Properties-->Web(tab on the left) and there in servers section you can give project Url and either select IIS Express or Local IIS

Comment: @Prashant: these options are available for Web Applications not Web Sites.

Answer (score 5):

Having the following configuration made it work, i.e. http://localhost:59903/myapp works now as well as http://localhost:59903.

```
<site name="My Web Application" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\costa\Documents\webapps\My Web Application" />
    </application>
    <application path="/myapp" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\costa\Documents\webapps\My Web Application" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:59903:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Note the presence of two application elements.

See this as well: [IIS7: Possible causes of 'Unrecognized configuration path' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371120/iis7-possible-causes-of-unrecognized-configuration-path-error)

Answer (score 2):

There has a way that you don't need to modify the configuration file which is much easier. And this is the answer from Microsoft.

1. In Visual Studio, on the **File** menu, click **Open** and then click **Web Site**.
2. In the dialog box, click the **Local IIS** icon.
3. In the top-right corner of the dialog box, click the **Create New Virtual Directory** button.
4. In the **Alias name** text box, type the name for your virtual directory.
5. In the **Folder** text box, type the fully qualified path to the physical directory where your files are located, or click the **Browse** button to browse to the location, and then click **OK**

That's it, 
  [you will be happy to see this result in your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUZ8n.png).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6cw6cfs.aspx

Comment: Thank you for solution, but I'm getting error "Unable to set permissions on directory '...' for account 'ASPNET'", do you know how to solve it?
I didn't find user "ASPNET" on my computer, but I allowed full access to my project directory to "All" in safety settings ot the path, but had no result.
I launched VS as admin, but also had no result.