# MVC application in a Virtual Directory: 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, iis-express, viewbag, virtual-directory

I have an installation of **IIS Express 10** on my local machine that I use for developing MVC applications. Normally, I use the following configuration in *applicationhost.config* for my sites, where I have no virtual directories defined:

```
<site name="Development Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
  <application path="/">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\dev\MyMVC" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

Using the above configuration, the MVC application can be accessed with no errors at http://localhost:8080

However, I recently tried to make the application accessible using a virtual directory (please note the path "C:\fake" as the root directory--IIS requires a site's root directory to be defined before any virtual directories are--see [How to configure a different virtual directory for web site project with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38756986/how-to-configure-a-different-virtual-directory-for-web-site-project-with-visual)). I created the virtual directory using the following configuration in *applicationhost.config*:

```
<site name="Development Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
  <application path="/">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\fake" />
  </application>
  <application path="/test/app">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\dev\MyMVC" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

**Using the above configuration and navigating to http://localhost:8080/test/app**, the MVC application begins to load, but I get the following error:

```
c:\dev\MyMVC\views\index.cshtml(14): error CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
```

What is the virtual directory configuration doing to cause this error? It works fine without the virtual directory.

**You can replicate this error using a fresh MVC template in Visual Studio, without touching any code other than what's in the applicationhost.config file, so I don't think the problem is in my code.**

Comment: What have you tried? Other posts indicate cache folder cleanup and so on, but you seem to try nothing at all yet.

Comment: @LexLi there is nothing to try in code, as the error is displayed without even touching the code (you can reproduce the error with a new, fresh, canned Visual Studio MVC template)

Comment: Microsoft has Help | Report a Problem, if you don’t know yet.

Comment: @user3163495 , try to put in your virtual directory basic web.config file, wich define razor assemblies, file f.e. http://textuploader.com/du24o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that not only does IIS Express require a root directory for the site as a whole to be defined, but also every virtual directory URL *segment* as well. So, it worked after changing the configuration to this (note the intermediate "/test" virtual directory):

```
<site name="Development Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
  <application path="/">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\fake" />
  </application>
  <application path="/test">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\fake" />
  </application>
  <application path="/test/app">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\dev\MyMVC" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

http://localhost:8080/test/app now works properly without the 'ViewBag' error